# CDI / JTA - Error during session replication: UnproxyableResolutionException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, jta

I am testing server failover in a Wildfly 26 cluster (using standalone-ha.xml config)

The application is a stateful JSF / Jakarta EE8 / CDI war deployment

We are using Deltaspike Data and JPA modules in DAO pattern (with @RequestScoped entity managers)

I have two nodes runnings 1 and 2 and perform the following steps:

- Login to a user account on Node 1 to create some session data.
- Perform a graceful shutdown of Node 1, logs show Node 1 has left the cluster and is reported in logs at Node 2
- Refresh browser
- Node 2 loads the replication session data then throws the exception pasted below to say that `com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.DelegatingTransactionManager` is not proxyable. The page doesn't render any content and I have to start a new HTTP session to be able to continue on Node 2

> [0m [31m11:31:47,479 ERROR [io.undertow.servlet.request] (default
> task-2) UT015005: Error invoking method requestInitialized on listener
> class org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener:
> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001435:
> Normal scoped bean class
> com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.DelegatingTransactionManager is not proxyable
> because it has no no-args constructor - Managed Bean [class
> com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.NarayanaTransactionManager] with qualifiers
> [@Any @Default].

Further down it references one of our CDI @ViewScoped beans (ManageCheers):

> Caused by: an exception which occurred:   in object of type
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.util.SerializableClientProxy    in field
> com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorBase.transactionManager
> in object
> com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired@2cbfe004
> in object of type
> com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.transactional.TransactionalInterceptorRequired
> in field
> org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptionContext.interceptorInstances
> in object
> org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptionContext@7ce2923f     in
> object of type org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptionContext
> in field
> org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.ctx     in
> object
> org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler@651c0cb2    in
> object of type
> org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler     in field
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.interceptorMethodHandler
> in object
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler@36f06fd5
> in object of type
> org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler
> in field
> com.myapp.actions.notifications.ManageCheers$Proxy$_$$*WeldSubclass.methodHandler
> in object
> com.myapp.actions.notifications.ManageCheers$Proxy$*$$*WeldSubclass@4e106109
> in object of type
> com.myapp.actions.notifications.ManageCheers$Proxy$*$$_WeldSubclass
> in object of type javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ViewMap  in object
> of type com.sun.faces.util.LRUMap

---

### -----UPDATE

The problem seems to be linked to the

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
```

annotation, if I remove this annotation from our CDI bean it does not occur, but then we have no transactions.

I notice that NarayanaTransactionManager is @ApplicationScoped so maybe the server shutdown is causing it to be re-created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Narayana, I forked the library and added a no-args constructor to the DelegatingTransactionManager and the exception no longer occurs.

Bug reported here:

https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JBTM/issues/JBTM-3703?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0):

Looks like com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.NarayanaTransactionManager is being put into your session state but is not compatible with the state replication.

Are you actually expecting this to be part of your state? Feels like it's not intentional

Comment: No its not intentional, I'm not referencing that class anywhere in my application code as far as I can see

Comment: In which case you might be referencing an interface that this is the implication for or at least used by the implementation. You mention that your entity managers are @RequestScoped so I wonder if you have an entity still attached to the entity manager or leaking per request into per session somewhere

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the use of @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED) in my CDI beans, when I remove this annotation it goes away

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe enable **sticky session** to avoid session replication (from one node to another) ?
https://docs.wildfly.org/26/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/configuration/filter/mod-cluster/balancer/index.html

Comment: I am already using stick sessions, replication is needed when I need to shutdown a server immediately